# Maven Archetype project repository issue

Tags: java, maven, mule, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have created a maven archetype project from my existing sample project. I published that jar file to a repository at https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/orgid/maven.
When i tried to create a project by running the command **mvn archetype:generate** is giving an error, saying it could not find the archetype in the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2  repository.
I have not configured repo.maven.apache.org in the maven settings.xml file. What changes i should make to settings.xml so it can refer to the desired repo at maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com repository. I have also configured the mirrors in settings.xml file

```
<mirror>
   <id>mirrorId</id>
   <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
   <name>mule repo exchange</name>
   <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/orgid/maven</url>
</mirror>
```

When i configured this mirror option , its giving the error -  No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Anypoint Exchange](https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/) provides a [Maven facade feature](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/exchange-maven-facade-api-http/) to be able to publish certain types of MuleSoft artifacts. It is not intended to be a complete Maven repository for general usage. According to the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/to-publish-assets-maven) currently the following types of objects are supported:

- Connectors
- Mule applications
- Examples
- Templates
- Policies

You have to use your own repository for this type of things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have managed to deploy the archetype, then add a Maven profile to your settings with your archetype repository:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>my-archetype-repository</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>archetype</id>
          <name>Mule Repository</name>
          <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/<YOUR_ORG_ID>/maven</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Then run your archetype with that profile:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Pmy-archetype-repository
```

And don't forget to add a server with your credentials for 'archetype'.